# cardinality of units in a commutative ring of cardinality odd

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How to prove the cardinality of units is even, if the ring has odd cardinality.?

Since |R| is odd then $|M_{i}|$ is odd for all maximal ideals $M_{i}$ in R.So $U(R)=R\backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}=|\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}R \backslash M_{i}|$.

how to pove after this

Comment: How about the context of your question?

Comment: if |R| is odd then how to prove |U(R)|= odd

Comment: To prove the  comaximal graph of odd cardinality commutative rings are eulerian, I am trying to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ring has odd cardinality, its characteristic is different from $2$.

If $u$ is a unit in $R$, then also $-u$ is a unit.